# What's the reasoning behind adding the "case" keyword to Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, pattern-matching

Apart from:

```
case class A
```

... *case* which is quite useful?

Why do we need to use `case` in `match`? Wouldn't:

```
x match {
  y if y > 0 => y * 2
  _ => -1
}
```

... be **much** prettier and concise?

Or why do we need to use `case` when a function takes a tuple? Say, we have:

```
val z = List((1, -1), (2, -2), (3, -3)).zipWithIndex
```

Now, isn't:

```
z map { case ((a, b), i) => a + b + i }
```

... *way* uglier than just:

```
z map (((a, b), i) => a + b + i)
```

...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second issue, anonymous functions that avoid the `case`, is a matter of debate:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-debate/Q0CTZNOekWk/z1eg3dTkCXoJ

Also: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/1260

For the first issue, the choice is whether you allow a block or an expression on the RHS of the arrow.

In practice, I find that shorter case bodies are usually preferable, so I can certainly imagine your alternative syntax resulting in crisper code.

Consider one-line methods.  You write:

```
def f(x: Int) = 2 * x
```

then you need to add a statement.  I don't know if the IDE is able to auto-add parens.

```
def f(x: Int) = { val res = 2*x ; res }
```

That seems no worse than requiring the same syntax for case bodies.

To review, a case clause is `case Pattern Guard => body`.

Currently, `body` is a block, or a sequence of statements and a result expression.

If `body` were an expression, you'd need braces for multiple statements, like a function.

I don't think `=>` results in ambiguities since function literals don't qualify as patterns, unlike literals like `1` or `"foo"`.

One snag might be: `{ case foo => ??? }` is a "pattern matching anonymous function" (SLS 8.5).  Obviously, if the case is optional or eliminated, then `{ foo => ??? }` is ambiguous. You'd have to distinguish case clauses for anon funs (where `case` is required) and case clauses in a `match`.

One counter-argument for the current syntax is that, in an intuition deriving from C, you always secretly hope that your match will compile to a switch table.  In that metaphor, the cases are labels to jump to, and a label is just the address of a sequence of statements.

The alternative syntax might encourage a more inlined approach:

```
x match {
  C => c(x)
  D => d(x)
  _ => ???
}
@inline def c(x: X) = ???
//etc
```

In this form, it looks more like a dispatch table, and the match body recalls the Map syntax, `Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)`, that is, a tidy simplification of the association.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for `scala-debate` link. I'm not sure why, as a developer, I personally need to differentiate between "pattern matching anonymous function" and normal anonymous function. Compiler could do that for me. ;) Also, see my comment to @ghik 's answer.

Comment: Does anyone have an updated link to scala-debate? That one seems to be erroring.

Comment: Sorry @PeterEhrlich answers aren't supposed to have links for that reason. Scala 3 has https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling.html to settle that debate. No one liked my answer anyway.

Answer (score 12):

First, as we know, it is possible to put several statements for the same case scenario without needing some separation notation, just a line jump, like :

```
x match {
       case y if y > 0 => y * 2
                          println("test")
                          println("test2")  // these 3 statements belong to the same "case"
}
```

If `case` was not needed, compiler would have to find a way to know when a line is concerned by the next case scenario.

For example:

```
x match {
   y if y > 0 => y * 2
   _ => -1
}
```

How compiler would know whether `_ => -1` belongs to the first case scenario or represents the next case?

Moreover, how compiler would know that the `=>` sign doesn't represent a literal function but the actual code for the current `case`?

Compiler would certainly need a kind of code like this allowing cases isolation:
(using curly braces, or anything else)

```
x match {
    {y if y > 0 => y * 2}
    {_ => -1}  // confusing with literal function notation
}
```

And surely, solution (provided currently by scala) using `case` keyword is a lot more readable  and understandable than putting some way of separation like curly braces in my example.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that you could write several lines for the same case *without* wrapping them in a block. +1 for that! If "enblocking" was obligatory, as I thought, then the compiler would easily know about particular case boundaries. While `case` in `match` is acceptable (although I'd like OCaml's `|` more), you've not refered to my second question (using case in function parameter matching).

Comment: This should have been picked as best answer

Answer (score 10):

Adding to @Mik378's answer:

When you write this: `(a, b) => something`, you are defining an anonymous `Function2` - a function that takes two parameters.

When you write this: `case (a, b) => something`, you are defining an anonymous `PartialFunction` that takes one parameter and matches it against a pair.

So you need the `case` keyword to differentiate between these two.

Comment: Not exactly. ;P This is so wicked to me:

    `scala> val f1: (Int, Int) => Int = { case (a, b) => a + b }`

renders:

    `f1: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>`

and

    `scala> val f2: ((Int, Int)) => Int = { case (a, b) => a + b }`

renders:

    `f2: ((Int, Int)) => Int = <function1>`

I'll probably ask another question 'bout that.

Comment: @MichałRus O_o that is indeed confusing. I wouldn't expect that the first example would even compile. I don't understand why Scala allows such syntax either.

Answer (score 2):

One of the key aspects of code readability is the words that grab your attention. For example,
`return` grabs your attention when you see it because you know that it is such a decisive action (breaking out of the function and possible sending a value back to the caller).

Another example is `break`--not that I like `break`, but it gets your attention.

I would agree with @Mik378 that `case` in Scala is more readable than the alternatives. Besides the compiler confusion he mentions, it gets your attention.

I am all for concise code, but there is a line between concise and illegible. I will gladly make the trade of 4n characters (where *n* is the number of cases) for the substantial readability that I get in return.

Comment: To me, OCaml's `|` would do better than `case`. You've not refered to the second part (function parameter matching).