# Using 'case' in PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

This is the syntax for method `reduceByKey`

```
def reduceByKey(func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)]
```

In a word count program I am practicing, I see this code,

```
val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x + y}
```

The application works with `(x, y)` instead of `case(x, y)`. What is the use of `case` here. I did also check the answer from @ghik [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471695/whats-the-reasoning-behind-adding-the-case-keyword-to-scala). but not able to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala supports multiple ways of defining anonymous functions. The "case" version is so called [Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions) which is more or less equivalent to:

```
(x: Int, y: Int) => (x, y) match { case (x, y) => x + y }
```

while version without `case` is pretty much what it looks like:

```
(x: Int, y: Int) => x + y
```

In this case simple `_ + _` would be enough though:

```
val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Probably the simplest case when you can benefit from using pattern matching is when you deal with Scala [Options](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option):

```
(x: Option[Int], y: Option[Int]) => (x, y) match {
    case (Some(xv), Some(yv)) => xv + yv
    case (Some(xv), _) => xv
    case (_, Some(yv)) => yv
    case _ => 0
}
```

Comment: thanks. What exactly is the benefit of using case(x, y) instead of using (x, y). I can still achieve the same result using (x, y) instead of case(x, y)

Comment: In this particular case I cannot see any benefits, but generally speaking pattern matching is much more flexible, especially when you want to decompose data structures or you work with [case classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) where pattern matching can be used to recover constructor parameters.